# Make div stick to table?

Tags: php, html, css

I really need help with solving this, it has been like 2 days and I still have not been able to figure it out. I basically run a server for a game, and I have a Table for the things you do. I have been refusing to ask someone here because I doubt anyone will ever know what this is for, but I will just leave it as it is.

There is a white button on peoples profiles called "Extend Userpage" an userpage is where the user is allowed to put images, text or whatever on their profiles, just for fun. However, when someone has an userpage, the grey background gets repositioned and I REALLY need to have it stick to the "Top Plays" Table.

[Here's a link to the code](http://pastebin.com/UnhVKSkH)

[Here's a video showing the problem](https://a.pomf.cat/nxtkyl.mp4)
I need it to stick to the "Top Plays" like it does on the second profile I go to. (Kawaii Rikka)

Help is so kindly appreciated.

Comment: Is your project public? Can you provide a URL? If not, you need create a runnable snippet like in your question using [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com/).

Comment: Well, yeah It's public. You can visit it at "Jenbancho.ml" However, you would need to register to see all the content.

Comment: Maybe it's problem with float? Have you tried adding div after user content box like this: `<div style="clear:both"></div>`?